# How to set SPF TXT for this scenario?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I need to add two mailing list servers, in addition to the normal mail servers, to serve two domains. Hopefully any of the two mailing server can send email for any of the two domains.

```
    domain    mailing server    default mx server
   --------  ----------------  -------------------
1) foo.com     emm.foo.com       mail.foo.com
2) bar.com     emm.bar.com       mail.bar.com
```

How can I set the SPF records for the two domains above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use explicit IP address in SPF record:

```
"v=spf1 ip4:<IP of mail.foo.com> ip4:<IP of mail.bar.com> -all"
```

Creating SPF record for each domain, then send mail to check.

Comment: Is there a way to specify wildcard (say, `*.foo.com`) of servers can send email on behalf of `bar.com` domain?

Comment: According to http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4, I think there is no way.

Comment: Do I need to add the original `mx` server? i.e. put `mx` in front of `-all`: `"v=spf1 ip4:<IP of mail.foo.com> ip4:<IP of mail.bar.com> mx -all"`

Comment: Don't need, because your mx points to mail.foo.com, mail.bar.com, which were listed in SPF record.